# Jcarousel Slider % Width Issue

Tags: jquery, width, jcarousel

Can this jcarousel slider be modified so the width of the slide is 100%? i.e. shrink the window width and the text wraps accordingly to fit, and the slider remains intact.

Lines 8 & 23 of the CSS are the width, but when set to 100% the slider breaks... presumably because the li width stretches out to the ul width (which must be wide enough to accommodate all the li items).

http://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/3FhcQ/38/

```
#wrapper {
position:relative;
width: 980px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
#slider {
width:100%; /* I want this to be 100% */
height:300px;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden
}
#slider ul {
list-style:none;
list-style-type:none;
position:absolute;
padding:0;
margin:0;
width:200000px;
}
#slider ul li {
position:relative;
width:100%; /* I want this to be 100% */
height:300px;
float:left;
background:#e8e8e8;
}
```